# UILabel Truncate With Ellipsis from the Left

Tags: ios, objective-c

If there's a long text on a UILabel, I want to have the ellipsis form and truncate from the left rather than the right.

Is there a good way to do it without bashing for text sizes or only allowing certain string lengths?

Example:

Instead of:

```
This is a long senten...
```

I want:

```
...is a long sentence.
```

Answer (score 2):

As according to the [UILabel Class Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/lineBreakMode) you want to use:

```
self.lineBreakMode =  NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead
```

You need to adjust the lineBreakMode value:

> The technique to use for wrapping and truncating the label’s text.

All the options are:

```
enum {
   NSLineBreakByWordWrapping = 0,
   NSLineBreakByCharWrapping,
   NSLineBreakByClipping,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail,
   NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle 
};
typedef NSUInteger NSLineBreakMode
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow literally a few minutes later, I discovered `NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead`

So just do `label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead`